# Infinite number of events and an element of their intersection

Tags: statistics

This is actually question 3 of chapter 1 in 'All of Statistics' by Larry Wasserman. It feels like an easy question and I think I'm missing something very basic here.

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space and $A_1,A_2,A_3...$ be events. Define $B_n$ = $\bigcup_{i=n}^\infty A_i$

Part (b) is where I'm stuck : prove that w $\in$ $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty$$B_n$ IFF w belongs to an infinite number of events $A_1, A_2...$ The wording threw me off at first as I thought that it was all A events, rather than just an 'infinite number'.

Part (a) (which I've done) asks to show that $B_1 \supset B_2 \supset ...$
For part (b),  if w is the the element of an infinite number of $A_i$ events then, since there's a finite number of As of which it isn't an element, there'll be a certain number k for which w will be an element of all $A_{n\geqslant k}$ from which it follows that it'll be an element of all $B_{n\geqslant k}$. On the other hand, if w is an element of an intersection of all the $B_i$, do I prove that the only way that intersection is not an empty set is if it includes an infinity of A events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x \in B_n$ **iff** there is some $k \ge n$ such that $x \in A_k$.

Hence $x \in \cap_n B$ **iff** for all $n$ there is some $k \ge n$ such that $x \in A_k$.

Suppose $x \in \cap_n B$. Pick $n=1$, then there is some $k_1$ such that $x \in A_{k_1}$. Now pick $n=k_1+1$, then there is some $k_2 \ge k_1+1$ such that
$x \in A_{k_2}$, etc, etc. This gives an infinite sequence $k_n$ such that
$x \in A_{k_n}$.

For example, take $\Omega = \{\pm 1\}$, and $A_n = \{+1\}$ if $n$ is even and $A_n = \{-1\}$ if $n$ is odd. Then $B_n = \Omega$ for all $n$ so that $\cap_n B_n = \Omega$, however it is clear that $+1$ is not an element of all $A_n$.